# QT5 Align OSX QTabWidget left

Tags: c++, qt5

Having an issue with QTabWidget in QT5.

Basically I have an app that whose main content area is a QTabWidget. On Ubuntu and Windows the tabs are aligned to the left. On OSX, however, the tabs start from the center of the tab widget. I've tried changing the alignment with the following:

```
QTabWidget { alignment: left; }
```

As well as

```
QTabWidget:tab-bar { alignment: left }
QTabBar { alignment: left; }
```

Is it possible to get left-aligned tabs on OSX in QT5?

Answer (score 4):

For reference to anyone coming here from Google

```
QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    left: 0; 
}
```

will do the trick.

Comment: when I do this in conjunction with `tab_widget.setTabsClosable(True)` the close buttons no longer appear! Does this stylesheet override some setting necessary for the close buttons to appear?

Comment: @Lymphatus Is this still working for you? I can't get it to work